# why am I getting Error: Query was empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error when I try to use the following code! I don't understand the reason. I assume its something to do with the UPDATE but i dont get what it is!

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE pages SET pagebody = 'firstname'");

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You aren't selecting a database `mysql_select_db("", $con);` the first parameter should be the name of your database.

Comment: Seriously, before you waste any time debugging this code, stop using `mysql_query`. It's extremely dangerous and will lead to immense pain and suffering if someone manages to exploit your [unescaped SQL values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). PDO takes only [half an hour to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will provide significantly better safety if used properly, and will be supported in future versions of PHP.

Comment: You are calling `mysql_query` twice. The second time it actually is empty.

Comment: So many issues. I strongly recommend you follow a tutorial or guide.

Answer (score 1):

You don't select database here `mysql_select_db("[db name]", $con);`. And another thing, are you planning to update all entries in the pages table? Because you don't have a `WHERE` clause. The comments here have their points though.